# Extract columns based on a vector, how to get it in the right order?

Tags: r

I want to extract columns in a data frame based on a vector. When I do it I get the result in alphabetic order, but I want to get it in the original order. Any suggestion on how this can be done?

```
a <- sample(100,10)
c <- sample(100,10)
b <- sample(100,10)
g <- data.frame(a,c,b)
g <- colnames(g)

a <- sample(100,10)
c <- sample(100,10)
b <- sample(100,10)
d <- sample(100,10)
df <- data.frame(a,b,c,d)


names <- colnames(df)[colnames(df) %in% g]
names
[1] "a" "b" "c"

# but I want it as it is in data frame "g", a c b
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `match` instead of `%in%`:

```
colnames(df)[match(colnames(df), g, 0)]
#[1] "a" "c" "b"
```

Note:

```
`%in%`
#function (x, table) 
#match(x, table, nomatch = 0L) > 0L

intersect
#function (x, y) 
#{
#    y <- as.vector(y)
#    unique(y[match(as.vector(x), y, 0L)])
#}
```

Answer (score 2):

a small change to `colnames(df)[colnames(df) %in% g]` should do it

```
a <- sample(100,10)
c <- sample(100,10)
b <- sample(100,10)
g <- data.frame(a,c,b)
g <- colnames(g)

a <- sample(100,10)
c <- sample(100,10)
b <- sample(100,10)
d <- sample(100,10)
df <- data.frame(a,b,c,d)


names <- colnames(df[,g])
names 

[1] "a" "c" "b"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `intersect` :

```
intersect(g, colnames(df))
#[1] "a" "c" "b"
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `select`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
    select(all_of(g)) %>%
    names
#[1] "a" "c" "b"
```